# get user name asp.net windows auth

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

SO i made a simple web form, set in windows auth in iis. then i deployed it on my server and i try to log in. it prompts me a login box, i enter my infos, looks likes its working fine with active directory.

if i enter something wrong it wont work etc.

obviously i need to know who is the logged on user

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
```

i found this in other threads, but it wont work for me...

how do i get the info filled in the login box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<identity impersonate="true" />` in web config , fixed my problem.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx helped me.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you using `asp.net` `membership` provider you can get the current logged user

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

can be used to identify whether user successfully logged in or not

Comment: Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()); returns me AUTORITE NT\SERVICE RÉSEAU, edit , which is not the user i used to log in. i used davetest

Comment: use this to get username User.Identity.Name moreover this article got useful information regarding this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/2ea4be48-5f5d-46b4-9aca-d9a9531f0e33

Comment: This method worked for me. Setting `<identity impersonate="true">` _didn't_. In fact, setting impersonate to true gives me NT AUTHORITY\IUSR, which is the default anonymous IIS user.