# Get the username of the computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, credentials

I am using this line of code to get the username that the computer is logged into

```
 String windosUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

but the result that I am getting is that the string is empty string.

I would like to see the name of the person that is logged on the computer not the actual name of the computer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the computer user name in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245270/get-the-computer-user-name-in-a-web-application).

Comment: This only works if the website is being accessed on a local intranet using Windows NTLM authentication.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get user name asp.net windows auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615458/get-user-name-asp-net-windows-auth)

Comment: Does this help: [HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is Empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571036/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-empty) ?

Comment: You need to give more context. Is this an intranet site? Is this a public website? What's the purpose? Why can't you ask the user? What authentication model are you using? Have you considered the security implications of if the operating system let any visited webpage know what username you logged in with?

Comment: I'm guessing neither Windows Auth nor Forms auth is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
var username = this.Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

If this doesn't work I think it must be your IIS Settings, as It works fine for me.

Comment: This would more than likely return the user of the ASP.NET IIS process.

Comment: this dont give me the user that has logged into the system

Comment: it gave me the location of the program and not the username which has been logged in